# Replace target table from physical to a work table on Data Integration Studio

Tags: sas, data-integration

I know how to replace a work table with a physical one without losing mapping, logic etc...
Question is ,
is it possible doing the opposite?
I want to replace a target table at the end of my job, so that it would be located in work envirnment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are loading with a "Table Loader" transform then you will need to remove that and right click on the previous node and "Add Work Table".

Unfortunately this method would lose any logic that you had included in your "Table Loader" transform.

Comment: Yep. Thought so. Thank you for your answer, mjsqu